# Why isn't this root equation working out?

Tags: roots, quadratics

Suppose we have the equation

$\sqrt{3x-2}=\sqrt{x-2}+2$

I know the solutions are 2 and 6  but I can't figure out where I'm going wrong in the following

$(\sqrt{3x-2})^{2}=(\sqrt{x-2}+2)^{2}$

$3x-2=x-2+4\sqrt{x-2}+4$

$2x-4=4\sqrt{x-2}$

$4x^2-32x+48=0$

But this gives imaginary roots

If I rearrange it so that we have

$\sqrt{3x-2}-2=\sqrt{x-2}$

I now get real roots but they're still not 2 and 6

My question is two fold

1. how do I do this to obtain the proper solutions of two and six
2. why does rearranging it lead to different solutions, some real and some imaginary ?

Comment: $4x^2 - 32x + 48 = 0.$

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed That was just a typo. It still gives imaginary roots though

Comment: No, it doesn't. The correct equation gives the solutions $2$ and $6$.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=0%3D4x%5E2-32x%2B48

Please double check your work with a calculator next time.

Comment: @jjagmath embarrassing.  I just tackled this with not enough sleep.

Comment: @1mdlrjcmed I'm just going to delete this question . I thought it was a deeper problem bur I just made silly errors because I'm sleepy

Comment: I have no idea why this question is getting downvotes. The asker explained their problem, showed their work and formatted the question well. Are you people downvoting the question because OP made a mistake? If so, can you explain to me what *you* think this site is for?

Comment: To OP: If you are in the comfortable position to already know (some) solutions of an equation and you are unsure where an error occured in your solution process, a simple method is to put in the knowns solutions into the transformed equations. In this case, doing that for the quadratic equation would be possible for $x=2$ in your head, and for $x=6$ with a simple calculator. Then you would know that the error was in your solution to the quadratic equation. If the solutions don't work, you know the error is before, and you test more intermediate equations.

Answer (score 2):

$$4x^2-32x+48 = 0$$ can first be simplified to

$$x^2-8x+12 = 0$$

and this equation has a discriminant of $$b^2-4ac = (-8)^2-4\cdot 1 \cdot 12 = 64-48=16>0$$ which means the equation has real solutions.